# Non-standard examples of Distributions

Tags: examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory

Can somebody point me to examples of distributions which are not sums of delta functions or derivatives thereof. Also of course not integrals with local integrable functions.

Additional: is there a classification?

Comment: How about $\phi\mapsto\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx\right)$?

Comment: I think the first derivative of the so-called [Minkowski's Question Mark function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function) may be one such example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joelafrite made a good suggestion: consider the first distributional derivative of a function $f$ that is not absolutely continuous. By definition, this distribution acts as 
$$\phi\to -\int f\phi'$$

- If $f$ is increasing (like Cantor staircase and Minkowski's ?-function), then the distribution $f'$ is a measure.
- If $f$ has bounded variation, then $f'$ is a signed measure.
- For more extreme examples, such as the Weierstrass nowhere differentiable function, $f'$ is a distribution that is hard to  imagine or compare to any familiar object.

And of course, higher distributional derivatives of the same functions provide even more singular examples.

As for classification: a derivative is of *order* at most $k$ if its value on test function $\phi$ is bounded by $C^k$ norm of $\phi$. So, order $0$ distributions are signed measures. There are distributions of  every finite order, as well as of [infinite order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35482).

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I learned about the Minkowski's $?(x)$.